# Quick-look on UIImage in debug with Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimage, quicklook

Recently I can't quick-look objects in debug window.

Instead of view like this:

[image: tutorial]

I see this:

[image: my view]

I think it changed recently as I switched to Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2.
Do you know any solutions or is it update fault?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems like it's bug in Xcode and quick look is not working for optionals. If you try to force unwrap image you get quick look working.

[image]

In the example above quick look is not working for `image` but it working for `unwrapped` image.